# How to get the count of views of a particular event?

Tags: django, python-2.7

A user can create a event. For that event he can invite some guests and add them to that guests.

Now I want to know the count of the total number of views for that particular event.I have written a django-view to get the event details, can I implement cProfile on that view and can count the number of views? And also total number of views for all events.How to implement this?

If I can implement cProfile please tell me how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by cProfile, but you can keep track of which guests have viewed an event in the model:

An example models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()

class EventInvite(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(User)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This uses `django.contrib.auth.models.User` to represent guests. Then in your views.py update the `EventInvite` object when the guest views the event if they don't accept it.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from eventsApp import Event, EventInvite    

@login_required
def viewEvent(request, event_pk):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_pk)
    eventInvite = EventInvite.objects.get(event=event,guest=request.user)
    eventInvite.viewed = True
    eventInvite.save()

    return render_to_response("eventView.html", { 'event' : event })
```

**Edit - to count views of an individual event**

This can be achieved more simply, add a counter field in the `Event` model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    num_views = models.IntegerField()
```

Then in the event view, increment the counter every time the view for a given object is loaded:

```
def viewEvent(request, event_pk):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_pk)
    event.num_views += 1
    event.save()

    return render_to_response("eventView.html", { 'event' : event })
```

This will count the raw number of times the django app is requested for a view of that given `Event` object. It is possible to create a custom middleware class to perform this behaviour if required: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware, this would be handy if you wish to use the behaviour across multiple view methods for example.

If you wish to carry out the counting at the template level, something like this: https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount, might be more useful.

Is this more like what you were looking for?

I'm happy to adapt / explain it more, if required.

Comment: Hi Henry thanks for the answer, this will give me only the users who have viewed the events. What if the same user views the event for ten times? so, I want the number of times a particular event has been called.
I can simply put like this, suppose I am calling viewEvent every time a user wants to see the event then I want the count of How many times viewEvent function is called.

Comment: @user2936254 I have altered the view function to do this.